# Modify javascript in precompiled dll

Tags: javascript, asp.net, dll, precompiled

I have a web application project and I use precompiled `Dll` with fixed name.

I would like to know how to modify the *`java-script`* inside one precompiled `Dll`.

I have modified using notepad, but it gives `HttpException (0x80004005): file.aspx` has not been pre-compiled, and cannot be requested.

Thanks in advance

EDIT: I found the answer for this. Please use the following steps, if anyone faces the same issue.

1. Use Ildasm - dump it to il and .res

   > ildasm org_.dll /out=new.dll
2. Modify .res (javascript). Make sure that number of char in old and new res files match.
3. Use ilasm to create dll

   > ilasm /resource=new.res new.il /dll

Comment: Are you modifying the compiled DLL directly with notepad? Or are you modifying the code with notepad, then compiling the code to a DLL?

Comment: How to compile after modifying? Using VS?

Comment: Or I have to use reflector/ ilspy?

Comment: If you have direct access to the source code, you can compile using Visual Studio. In the toolbar, go to Build and click Build Solution. I suggest you edit the code in Visual Studio, as it will highlight errors as you write code, provide syntax highlighting, and a wealth of other features.

Comment: There problem here is, I don't have old source code. Now bug is on older version and to fix this I need to modify one line in JS. So want to modify directly...